# Match two strings from a text file and user input? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I was able to load a text file in a Flash file, but I am unable to match two strings from a text file and the user input.

The purpose of this AS3 code: to match the text file and user input, and if it matches, the score will increase by 1. Else, the score will increase by 0.

Here is my code:

```
var uScore :Number = 0;

stop();

var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var textURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("q1.txt");

textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var textData:String = new String(textLoader.data);
    dy1.text = textData;
}

textLoader.load(textURLRequest);




function goURL(event:MouseEvent):void {

var textLoader2:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var textURLRequest2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("answer1.txt");

    var textData2:String = new String(textLoader2.data);
    var name1 = trace(textData2);


textLoader2.load(textURLRequest2);

    var myURL = url1.text;
    if(myURL == name1){
        uScore += 1;
        uScoreURL.text = uScore+"";
        nextFrame();
    }
    else{
        uScore+=0;
        uScoreURL.text = uScore+"";
        nextFrame();
    }
}

        trace(uScore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You code has a strange assignment:

```
var name1 = trace(textData2);
```

replace it with

```
var name1 =textData2;
```

it should work then if there isn't a bug in some other place.

And you don't need to `uScore+=0;`. Just delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, replacing that statement still does not work.

Comment: where you compare if(myURL == name1) put a trace(myURL, name1) one line before that, you'll know if some string is null or "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your code, you were doing a few things out of order - here is the revised code that should get you where you need to be

```
var uScore :Number = 0;

stop();

var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var textURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("q1.txt");

textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var textData:String = new String(textLoader.data);
    dy1.text = textData;
}

textLoader.load(textURLRequest);

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getNumber);

var textLoader2:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
textLoader2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler2);

function completeHandler2(event:Event):void
{
   var textData2:String = new String(textLoader2.data);
    var name1 = textData2;
    trace(name1);

    var myURL = url1.text;
    if(myURL == name1){
        uScore += 1;
        uScoreURL.text = uScore+"";
        nextFrame();
    }
    else{
        uScore+=0;
        uScoreURL.text = uScore+"";
        nextFrame();
    }
}

function getNumber(event:MouseEvent){
    var textURLRequest2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("answer1.txt");

    textLoader2.load(textURLRequest2);
}

        trace(uScore);
```

The only thing that I really added that you didn't have is a button with the variable name `btn` to check the answer - you can rework that to however you want to check for the answer.